# Set field if another field contains a value in Twig

Tags: twig

I am trying to add a value to a field if a certain value is present in another field using Twig.

I am new to Twig.

Trying to set the field value (If postcode contains NE1 set cc-email field to ccEmail)

```
{% if postcode == "NE1" %}
    {% set ccEmail = "email@email.com" %}
{% else %}
    {% set ccEmail = "" %}
{% endif %}
```

The cc-email where ccEmail must be added

```
<label class="hidden">CC Email</label>
<input id="cc-email" class="hidden cc-email" type="text" maxlength="255" name="Email1" value="{{ ccEmail }}" placeholder="CC Email" fieldType=9 />
```

The postcode field to see if the postcode matches

```
<input id="postcode" class="postcode" type="text" name="SingleLine4" value="" fieldType=1 maxlength="255" placeholder="Postcode *" required />
```

Comment: "*a certain value is present in another field*" - What do you mean with this? When an user types this inside `postcode`? This is not possible with `twig` as it is rendered server side. You'll need to resort to JavaScript if you want to adjust content based on user interaction